# sinch custom push notification misbehaving

Tags: android, sinch

I'am using my own backend for routing push notifications. Am able to relay the sinch payload successfully to recipients but problem is, video calls gets reported as voice calls at the recipient's end.This problem occurs when I disable `setSupportActiveConnectionInbackground` and dicide to use my own push implmentation.Voice calls work fine. What am I doing wrong

[image: screen]
this is how am setting up sinch.

Comment: Is sinch push notification good enough to determine that user is not online and can you help me if not online then I can receive something to update  Offline status using api in DB. Please HELP ! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calls are signaled with onIncoming call, you check the call for Video in the callDetails isVideoOffered

Comment: I actually was able to fix it by using `Call.getCallDetails.isVideoOffered()`. But this reveals a bug in your SDK. It seems you don't add the call headers to the push notification payload and there's no way to relay headers together with the sinch specific payload. on the receiving client even I send it as custom data  in the push notification payload

Comment: Is sinch push notification good enough to determine that user is not online and can you help me if not online then I can receive something to update  Offline status using api in DB. Please HELP ! :(

Comment: push wont give you a reply back, push is push is async and will be delivered when it delivers.

Comment: I mean the call specific headers are not added to the push payload.

Comment: @SamH67 I don't think so. You have to implement this yourself